# Выбор периода в календаре с даты по дату, в конечном итоге хочу получить 2 даты, начало и конец в текстбоксы

Tags: c#, wpf

я только начал изучать C# и плохо еще понимаю, но хочу на практике научиться.
Может есть у кого ссылка на готовый вариант чтобы я его изучил или поможете создать его.
Так же буду признателен если подскажете лучший материал для изучения(платный\бесплатный).
Может уже есть библиотеки какие уже с этим решением?

Решение нашёл, как оказывается просто.

```
  text1.Text = ( DateReport.SelectedDates.Min () ).ToString ();
  text2.Text = ( DateReport.SelectedDates.Max () ).ToString ();
```

Comment: [Datepicker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datepicker?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 6, 1, 7, 47, 0);
textBox1.text = thisDay.ToString("d");
textBox2.text = date1.ToString("d");
```

Так-же рекомендую почитать документацию именно [этой структуры](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0) и внимательно посмотреть свойства, поля и методы.

Comment: спасибо за наводку)

Comment: @АлександрФелюгин, лучшее спасибо-выбор моего ответа :)